# Recurrence relation for Jacobi polynomials with negative parameter $\beta$

Tags: recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

The Jacobi polynomials $P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(z)$ have the following recurrence relation in $n$ (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials)):

$2n(n+\alpha+\beta)(2n+\alpha+\beta-2)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(z)$
$=(2n+\alpha+\beta-1)\Big((2n+\alpha+\beta)(2n+\alpha+\beta-2)z+\alpha^2-\beta^2\Big)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_{n-1}(z)$
$-2(n+\alpha-1)(n+\beta-1)(2n+\alpha+\beta)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_{n-2}$ .

I'm trying to use this to write a program for calculating the polynomial. However for some of the parameter values I need (e.g. $n=2$, $\alpha=4$ and $\beta=-6$) the relation is not valid, since the factor in front of $P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(z)$ is zero.

Does anyone know if there is a different relation valid in these cases? Or otherwise have ideas on how I can deal with these cases without completely changing the program (e.g. not using recurrence relations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own library implementation $\alpha+\beta$ shall not be a negative integer. Many other implementations assume $\alpha, \beta > -1,$ because for these values the orthogonality relation holds. If you really want these unusual ranges for $\alpha,  \,\beta$ you can use relations to the Gauss hypergeometric function ${_2}F_{1}$. If (as in your case) $\alpha$ is no negative integer there is
$$P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(z)
=\frac{(\alpha+1)_n}{n!} {_2}F_{1}\left(-n,1+\alpha+\beta +n; 1+\alpha; \frac{1-z}{2}\right)
$$
which will give for example 
$$P^{(4,-6)}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{217}{16}$$
A general formula for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you can find at the [Wolfram function](http://functions.wolfram.com/05.06.02.0001.01) site:
$$P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(z)
= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-n)_k (\alpha+\beta +n+1)_k (\alpha+k+1)_{n-k}}{k!}\left(\frac{1-z}{2}\right)^k$$
With your parameters the polynomial is (if I did not make any mistakes)
$$P^{(4,-6)}_2\left(z\right)=\frac{49}{4}+\frac{5}{2}z+\frac{1}{4}z^2$$

Comment: Thanks! Btw if I understand correctly it seems the orthogonality relation holds universally: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0377042701005891/1-s2.0-S0377042701005891-main.pdf?_tid=b9e15a46-4170-11e3-90ee-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1383143996_0956703baa9fc288a719144eb348a8e2

Comment: I must thank **you**. I had never heard of __Sobolev orthogonality__!