# Applying Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonality

We have $f_0(x), f_1(x), \cdots$. where $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. These polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the inner prodoct
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-1}^{+1} f(x)g(x)(1-x^2)^{\lambda}dx, \quad \lambda \geq -\frac{1}{2},$$
and they satisfies $f_i(1)=1$ for all $i$.

I want to determine a recurrence relation $f_n(x)$ (or $f_{n+1}$ as below).
I started with applying Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization and I get stuck at
$$f_{n+1}(x) = xf_n(x) - \frac{\langle f_n,xf_n\rangle}{\langle f_n,f_n\rangle}f_n(x) - \frac{\langle f_{n-1},xf_n\rangle}{\langle f_{n-1},f_{n-1}\rangle}f_{n-1}.$$
I want to compute recurrence relation for $f_{n}$ with out the inner products in it.
Any ideas?

Comment: this polynomials are called Gegenbauer polynomials and they are a special kind of Jacobi polynomials which recurrence relation is given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544770/recurrence-relation-for-jacobi-polynomials-with-negative-parameter-beta and for a proof you can see one in Szegő book

Comment: Thanks @Hamza, I already know their name but I am trying to find the recurrence relation which is not in Szegő book.